# Как изменять цвета кнопки используя QPalette?

Tags: python, pyqt, qcolor, qpalette, qcolordialog

Могу ли я при помощи `QPalette` изменить цвет кнопки как-нибудь так :

```
self.ButtonName.setPalette(QtGui.QPalette(self.color))

self.color = QtWidgets.QColorDialog.getColor(QtCore.Qt.green, self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете. Обратите внимание, что вам надо установить `app.setStyle('Fusion')`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette, QColor
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = QPushButton('изменить цвета кнопки', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.click)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)

        self.palette = self.palette()
        self.palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(3, 18, 14))

        self.palette.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor('red'))  

        self.setPalette(self.palette)

        self.color_dialog = QtWidgets.QColorDialog(self)
        self.color_dialog.currentColorChanged.connect(self.on_currentColorChanged)
        self.color = QColor(0, 0, 128)

    def click(self):
        self.color_dialog.exec_()     
        self.palette.setColor(QPalette.Button, self.color)
        self.setPalette(self.palette)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
    def on_currentColorChanged(self, color):
        self.color = color


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setStyle('Fusion')                              # <----- !!!
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]